# Progress bar with value min and max in Android

Tags: android

I want to implement this progress bar for my product selling

[image]

I have total number and selling product number. How can I implement this progress bar with this design ?

Comment: I have online selling ,and have this progress

Comment: @ben75 I don't know how implement that

Comment: You will find the best resource is google / Stackoverflow. Before asking a question, check an answer isn't easily avaliable already. This could have been easily answered with a google search..

Comment: For what reason. Google and SO are readily available to answer your questions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this code

```
<ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progressBarSell"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="10dp"
       android:max="26"
       android:progress="12" />
```

## ---------------------------------------------

```
progressBarSell.setProgress(Total - Remaining);
progressBarSell.setMax(Total);
```

That's work fine

Answer (score 0):

you can use SeekBar instead of ProgressBar, for more information visit the link:

http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/
https://github.com/AndroSelva/Vertical-SeekBar-Android
http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/an-android-seekbar-for-your-mediaplayer/

```
///////

seek6.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){   
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

//TODO My code goes here

int CurrentLevel = seek6.getProgress();
    if (CurrentLevel < 30) CurrentLevel = 30;
    seek6.setProgress(CurrentLevel);

}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
boolean fromUser){

}
});
```